# Resizing any image in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, image

Magento has this great helper to resize product images but I'd like to resize any image from PHTML template files.

Now I could use the Varien_Image (lib/Varien/Image) class but it doesn't implement caching which is in my opinion required for resizing.

Is there an extension you can recommend for this or any other solution or should I build my own?

Comment: If the intention is to resize image files used in layout, the Google Pagespeed Apache/Nginx plugin will do that automagically for you. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize#resize_images

Comment: Hm that's nice, Ill look into that for my own server. However it's on an Apache (server) level and I do not always have access to that for every shop I build. I'm looking for a solution that is easy to implement without changing server configuration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution in the form of an extension so build my own which you can [download on github](https://github.com/dmanners/rkimages).

@Philwinkle's suggestion to use Googles Mod Pagespeed would have been easier but unfortunately in the case it was not possible to modify the server configuration.

**Usage**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('rkimages/image')->run('path/to/your/image')->resize(135); ?>" alt="Your Alt Here" />
```

Comment: By @Patos: Nice work. How do you use it or call it?

Comment: Bump...I would also like to use it could you add an example here :)

Comment: Your extension is not available any more?

Comment: @Simon ah had some issues with that module regarding feedback on it so removed it. I can look for a copy this weekend if thats ok?

Comment: Thanks Sander, not sure if I will use it, but would be cool in any case since it is linked here :)

Comment: You can find the `rkimages` module here these days: https://github.com/dmanners/rkimages